# IIS can't rewrite outbound rule having soket.io query

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am banging my head into the wall. Every single URL is re-written by IIS URL Rewrite module but the response having `https://nginx-server/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486150196479-0` when I open my Network tab in chrome, I see:

```
https://nginx-server.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486150196479-0
https://nginx-server.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486150196479-0
https://iis-reverse-proxy-server.com/t/assets/images/chat-logo.png
https://iis-reverse-proxy-server.com/config.js
https://iis-reverse-proxy-server.com/t/assets/images/main_logo.png
```

I am trying to reverse proxy the `https://nginx-server`. IIS reverse proxy rewrite all the URL that are accessing nginx except those having `socket.io` URI in them . Same thing happens when some `api` is called and the IIS just stop rewriting outbound rules.

this is my web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://nginx-server.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^(.*)?://nginx-server.com/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}://iis-reverse-proxy-server.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**==========Edit:===========**
This is my updated web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://nginx-server.com/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
                
            </rules>
        
            <outboundRules>
            
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^(.*)?://nginx-server.com/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}://iis-reverse-proxy-server.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
            
            
           
                <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncoding" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Atag" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match pattern="href=(.*?)https://nginx-server.com/(.*?)\s" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="href={R:1}https://iis-reverse-proxy-server.expertflow.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="elementencodedaction" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match pattern="action=(.*?)https://nginx-server.com/(.*?)\\" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="‘action={R:1}https://iis-reverse-proxy-server.expertflow.com/{R:2}\" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
                    </preCondition>
                    <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".+" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: Learn how to use a tool like Fiddler to study the actual HTTP response message in whole, so that you know how the outbound rule fails to process it. That's not surprising as your current rule only applies to an HTML response and modifies its internal links. If the response is not HTML, then you need to write extra rules.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it. Can you please indicate any good article to follow ? I want to rewrite all the responses coming from nginx.

Comment: 1) Why IIS must be in front of nginx? nginx is already a common web server to expose to the public, so IIS gives no extra benefit. 2) I already mentioned the key things you should do. Whether there are articles on the same you should ask a search engine.

Comment: 1. Yes I agree on IIS not giving any extra benefit. Nginx is used by my application and the requirement is to reverse proxy it by IIS. 
2. I have updated the outbound rewrite rule so that it captures all the protocols but still no gain. Do I need to rewrite it by using conditions? Like rewrite it by capturing `HTTP_HOST`  and `REQUEST_URI` ?

Comment: You can try to use [failed bad request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to get detailed error information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the efforts for intended help. It turned out the config file in the application re writing the URL so that is why IIS could not be able to rewrite the URL. Updating URL in config file resolved my issue.